# Give a list of a from area code and to area code and a distance between them,which data structure?

Tags: java, data-structures

What data structure i can use to lookup given a fromCode and toCode apart from hashMap which results in more number of entries in the memory.
We are ok with log(n) efficiency also.
Example data:

```
fromCode    toCode  distance
100          200     10
100          300     20
-----      ----     ----
```

Assume fromcode and tocode are some integer values and you might get sorted data as well.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Software Engineering. I'm guessing this was downvoted because it's a simple, standard data structure, and whatever your OS library provides will be fine. If not, you'll need to give us more info, and perhaps put in a bit more thought.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a simple key-value map: an area code as key and its lat/long coordinate pair as the value.

This will have an O(n) size where n is the number of area codes — whereas the from/to arrangement will have O(n<sup>2</sup>) storage cost since it is a matrix of n x n.

To find distance between from & to area codes, you do two lookups, one using from-area code to get from-location coordinate, and one using to-area code to get to-location coordinate.  Simple math will compute the distance between the two coordinates.